# Python regular expression shortening

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I'm analysing log file using regular expression.
Log example:

```
<teststep timestamp="12040.310594" level="0" type="user" ident="1.2" result="pass">Signal STATUS_GET_VALUE response time Ok,\nSignal response time: 0.000000 [ms] \nSignal response time limit set: 100.000000 [ms]</teststep>
```

I need to extract **timestamp** and **Signal response time**.

My solution to this problem:

```
with open('report.xml') as f:
for line in f:
    if 'Signal response time: ' in line:
        timeStampL = re.findall('timestamp="\d*.\d*"', line)
        responseTimeL = re.findall('Signal response time: \d*.\d*',
                                   line, re.IGNORECASE)
        timeStamp = float(re.findall('\d+.\d+', timeStampL[0])[0])
        responseTime = float(re.findall('\d+.\d+', responseTimeL[0])[0])
```

I'm sure that this is not the shortest and the best way to get this data.
Would you like to suggest me a better approach?

Comment: Noo.... don't process XML/HTML with regexes: use BeautifulSoup, XPath, elementtree,...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem much of the payload here, though, is not structured XML. So it doesn't seem that unreasonable.

Comment: A better way is not not repeatedly match the same line over and over again. A single regex can easily pull out the two values you appear to be interested in so write that regex. Or leave it as it is if it works and is not a performance concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the attribute value and the element text using `BeautifulSoup` like this:

Since the text value `Signal STATUS_GET_VALUE response time Ok,\nSignal response time: 0.000000 [ms] \nSignal response time limit set: 100.000000 [ms]` comes with `\n` separators, you can use them to `split()` your data and get only the `0.000000 [ms]`.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_code = '<teststep timestamp="12040.310594" level="0" type="user" ident="1.2" result="pass">Signal STATUS_GET_VALUE response time Ok,\nSignal response time: 0.000000 [ms] \nSignal response time limit set: 100.000000 [ms]</teststep>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")

for test in soup.find_all('teststep'):
    print(test.get('timestamp'))
    print(test.text.split("\n")[1].split(":")[1].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
12040.310594
0.000000 [ms]
```

---

P.s.: You can remove the `[ms]` at `0.000000 [ms]` by changing this:

`test.text.split("\n")[1].split(":")[1].strip()`

to this:

`test.text.split("\n")[1].split(":")[1].strip().replace(" [ms]", "")`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get the desired result, would be to use an XML/HTML parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to locate the element, get the `timestamp` attribute (in `BeautifulSoup` you can treat an element as a dictionary when it comes to reading the attributes) and extract the "Signal response time" with a regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: from bs4  import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: data = """<teststep timestamp="12040.310594" level="0" type="user" ident="1.2" result="pas
    ...: s">Signal STATUS_GET_VALUE response time Ok,\nSignal response time: 0.000000 [ms] \nSignal
    ...:  response time limit set: 100.000000 [ms]</teststep>"""

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [5]: pattern = re.compile(r"Signal response time: ([0-9.]+)")

In [6]: elm = soup.find("teststep", text=pattern)

In [7]: print(elm["timestamp"], pattern.search(elm.get_text()).group(1))
12040.310594 0.000000
```